# Adapt UI to changes on label size

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-interface, text

I'm trying to adapt the UI of an app so that it works well with any translation. As expected, many of the labels change size considerably with each respective translation. Most of the labels have a textbox right next to them, so when the text changes in size everything gets messed up (such as the label overlapping part of the textbox).

What's the best way of approaching this? Is there a way of simply using anchors to have everything position automatically? I know it could be done by using a flow layout panel, but I think that may be overdoing it and it would mean having to add tons of new controls. I'd like to know if there's a simpler solution.

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel` is your answer - use it

Comment: This is one big reason why some people switch over to XAML.

Comment: @tgolisch WPF is better but also a learning curve. This is why some people still develop win forms.

Comment: @T.S. TableLayoutPanel helps me do what I need, but I was hoping for an even easier method... sigh. Thanks.

Comment: you can make your controls unmovable. But I have build complex, robust, configurable, resizable interfaces using nested `TableLayoutPanels`. This is by far the easiest way to configure your form layout unless you program yourself a dynamic way of control placement. I've done that too.

Comment: @T.S C# .Net also has a "learning curve", however that doesn't justify people to write code in COBOL or another obsolete technology anymore in 2014.

Comment: @HighCore You right. But the person who asked the question has no time or need to learn WPF right now barbecue he/she tries to solve control layout problem.

Comment: Or he may be dealing with a very large app he didn't build and cannot redo from scratch. I like WPF and would love to work daily with it, but I don't have that luxury.